# Artisan 'Nothing to migrate' error with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

## Synopsis

I have a package which contains a `database/migrations` directory, within contains a number of migrations.  I have a `tests` directory which contains one test with one assert.

I wish to unit test migrations using [phpunit](/questions/tagged/phpunit).

### Occurring Problems

I run PHP Unit and my test fails:

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /var/www/.../phpunit.xml

F

Time: 594 ms, Memory: 15.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) MigrationTest::testTableExists
Failed asserting that false is true.

/var/www/../tests/MigrationTest.php:31

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

This command does't create any tables in the test database, it does create the migration table in the test database.

I then attempted to run the migration on the command line:

```
$ php artisan migrate --env=testing --path=/vendor/../database/migrations/
Migration table created successfully.
Migrated: 2015_.._table
Migrated: 2015_.._table
Migrated: 2015_.._table
```

The `--env=testing` argument has been completely ignored and my tables were migrated to the production database (*NOTE: by production database I do mean development, but the default/production settings are incorrectly used*)

I added the develop database credentials to `phpunit.xml`:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test"/>
    <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="test"/>
    <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="test"/>
</php>
```

My testcase is:

```
<?php

class MigrationTest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__. '/../../../../bootstrap/app.php';
        $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->artisan('migrate', ['--env' => 'testing', '--path' => __DIR__.'/../database/migrations']);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        //$this->artisan('migrate:rollback', ['--path' => __DIR__.'/../']);

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testTableExists()
    {
        $hasTable = Schema::hasTable('table_name');

        $this->assertTrue($hasTable);
    }
}
```

During the test I can use `dd` to dump out the `env()` data and the database credentials are correctly set to `test, test and test`.

I'm really baffled as to how to solve this problem.

Comment: I am running into this same issue and have come to the conclusion that runDatabaseMigration() is fired after the setUp() method(s) completed. I haven't yet been able to figure an elegant solution around this, other than to extract this out to a custom setup method and call that from every test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems with this was the use of `--path` because the migrations can only migrate up and they cannot migrate down.  So, the best practice is to use either:

- Artisan `vendor:publish` and copy into `./tests/`, or
- Add the `/vendor/<namespace>/<package>/tests/` directory to PHPUnit

I opted for the latter because this keep the application cleaner and means only the packages paths need to be maintained along with any changes to `composer.json`.

So essentially it is a case of adding multiple `<directory>` definitions inside the phpunit.xml.

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
        <directory>./vendor/VENDOR/PACKAGE/tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```